# Use Rails form element in 'show' view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, user-interface, state

I'd like to have a split-dropdown button ([twitter bootstrap style](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)) in my show view so user can change the current 'state' for their 'job' using a collection (bids, in_progress, complete, canceled).

Here's how I'm current changing the states in the my _form (works fine):

```
<%= f.input :state, :collection => %w(bids in_progress complete canceled), :checked => 'bids', :as => :radio_buttons %>
```

But I'd rather the user not have to go through the entire form just to change the state. Would be nice for them to change the state 'on the fly' if you will.

How should I go about converting this to a dropdown and use it outside of my form? Note - I still want to retain the ratio collection in my form.

Should I create a partial with just the button and render it in the 'show' view? Do I need to add something to my controller? Maybe it would be easier/better to use javascript? Lots of questions, not sure where to start. Thanks.

**Update**

I've created a partial with this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :state, collection: [ ['bids', 'Bid'], ['in_progress', 'In Progress'], ['complete', 'Complete'] ], label_method: :last, value_method: :first, :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %>
<% end %>
```

And added this bit of javascript:

```
$(this.form).submit();
```

This is not working - am I on the right track? It seems like this should submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new form with only the state field directly in the show view (or in a partial, doesn't really matter). Then have some javascript submit the form whenever the dropdown is changed.

If you use rails form-helper they will point the submit to the update action of the controller and since only the state attribute is present that's the only attribute that will be updated.

Comment: jlundqvist, see the update above. How would I go about using a form-helper in this situation? I read over the docs but do not fully understand how to use is in a situation with collections. Thanks.

Comment: You are using the form helper (`simple_form_for`). I'm guessing the problem is in the javascript you added to `:onchange`. Try something like `:onchange => ("$('#form_name').submit()")`.